# Multiprocessing.Pool is using more CPUs than stated processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run 540 reinforcement learning expeiments on a shared Ubuntu 20.04 server with 40 cores. Since I do not want to use the whole server for myself, I've decided to run them only on 4 cores, for which I am using the following code (Python 3.7.0).

```
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import EvalCallback
from stable_baselines3.common.logger import configure
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from vrpEnv import VRPEnv
import multiprocessing


expList= [*range(1, 541)]

ITERATIONS = 500
TIMESTEPS = 2048*10

def runExperiment(exp):
    models_dir = "models/" + exp
    log_dir = "logs/"

    rank = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]
    print(f"Processor {rank} working on case {exp}")

    env = env = VRPEnv()

    model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_dir, device='cpu')
   
    eval_callback = EvalCallback(env, best_model_save_path=models_dir,
                            eval_freq=40000, deterministic=True, render=False)

    new_logger = configure(format_strings = ["log", "csv", "tensorboard"])

    start_time = time.time()

    for _ in range(1, ITERATIONS+1):
        model.set_logger(new_logger)
        model.learn(total_timesteps = TIMESTEPS, reset_num_timesteps = False, tb_log_name = nombreExp, callback=eval_callback)

    print("---%s: %s minutos ---" % (exp, round((time.time() - start_time)/60, 2)))

    env.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 4)
    result = pool.imap(runExperiment, expList)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('END')
```

With `multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 4)` it should create 4 processes maximum at any given time, but when I look up the server CPU usage by using `htop` I see that all 40 CPUs are veing used by me, but I only expected to use 4 of them.

[CPU usage on Linux Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAQm7.png)

I understand that `processes = 4` does not mean using necessarily 4 cores, but it also does not make much sense to me for each process to use 10 cores (if that is what is happening?).

Is there a way to limit the number of CPUs being used?

I've tried using the `chunksize` parameter but the result did not change. Same with other Pool methods, such as `map` or `map_async`.

Comment: This is not a reasonable test. Your subprocess runs very quickly. So quickly that *htop* is probably not getting a clear view of what's going on. Add an arbitrary delay (sleep) into your subprocess and review what *htop* tells you

Comment: @Codist I have added the actual code used when the screenshot of _htop_ was taken.

Comment: what i suggest you to do, upload output of HTOP without running this code, to see how many of cores are actually used without this code

Comment: @Jondi What are PPO and EvalCallback? They may be multithreaded. You won't have more than 4 concurrent subprocesses but if the functions you're calling are multithreaded that could explain high CPU (core) utilisation

Comment: @ElvinJafarov When doing that, only one of the cores is at 100%, by a process ran by a coworker.

Comment: what about Codist question?

Comment: How many cores does it use when you replace `runExperiment` with a simply busy-loop `while True: pass`? How is "load average" affected (command `uptime`)? What does `mpstat 5` measure in the "% idle" column?

Comment: presumably your "reinforcement learning" library is also distributing work across cores for you.  various numeric libraries do this implicitly and if you're also using multiprocessing you often have to disable this so they don't interact badly with each other (e.g. end up going slower or even crashing due to lack of memory)

Comment: Assuming `VRPEnv` wraps a vectorized environment, that's where you're getting multiple additional processes... https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html

Comment: @Codist Both [PPO](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo.html) and [EvalCallback](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/callbacks.html#evalcallback) are methods from the Stable Baselines 3 library. I have tried removing the evalcallback and the problem stayed the same.

Comment: @maxy I have done the test with a busy `while True: pass` as suggested and only 4 cores where being used. In the busy loop, the load average is 1.20, 1.47, 1.46, and with my code  26.43, 7.64, 3.53 is displayed. I can't run `mpstat` right now because it is not installed in the server, I need to ask the admin.

Comment: @Jondi If you have `htop`, you can see the process/thread tree and that will give you some insights

Comment: @AKX No, `VRPEnv` does not wrap a vectorized environment. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/Jondiii/vrp-rl/blob/main/vrpEnv.py).